# How to increase donor speed on mariadb galera cluster?

Tags: mariadb, clustering, galera, network

hi currently i have database with size 200gb
and my every node at 1Gb/s so when 1 node is down and then 2 node will be donor i config mariadb donor with `wsrep_sst_method = rsync` method. but it's take long time (more 3 hours).

this impact from node network specifications ?
and need scaling up the network ?

Comment: What is the ping time between nodes?  What is the bandwidth of the network?   Have you tried methods other than `rsync`?

Comment: I didn't try other than rsync
because i got the current configuration from previously dba. and from previously dba documentation said rsync is the best method for galera cluster.

Comment: What are you doing, IST or SST?  Building a new node?  Repairing a node?

Comment: I do SST. and repairing node, and why wserp_sst_method using `rsync` because not need authentication